# Unable to access html page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hello i dont know what the problem.. why when i click on button about us i am not able to be in the new page, but the url in the website change. The page reads only the extended block but the new one no.

this is the template (only the one related to the buttons)

```
<div class="btn-group cust-dropdown pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle cust-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"role="button">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Documentation</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the view:

```
def base(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'active_page':'base'})

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {'active_page':'about'})
```

And the about html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}About{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h3>Summary</h3>
        <p> Our organization is related to </p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[The image link is here, only the extendable form appear when i click on about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy2kr.png)

Comment: Also post the parts of base.html where you define the blocks `title` and `content`. If you don't have those then this would be your problem/solution.

Comment: show the base.html

Comment: thank you are right.. my fault is in the base html .. the problem is resolved thanks a lot